Concurrent Producer Transactions on a Kafka Partition
Suppose two processes are executing two separate Kafka Publish Transactions of 10 messages each, parallelly. After both commit, will the messages from both transactions be interleaved in the partition? or Kafka guarantees that messages of the same transaction are grouped together in the partition? The different "producer workers" have different transactional IDs
I tried to check the kafka docs but could not find the required info
